# Chances of tunneling increased at low temperatures?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, temperature, quantum-tunneling

I have been giving a formula which states that the wavelength increases when the temperature decreases. When I plug this into the formula for the wavelength of Broglie, I get that my momentum decreases. When you plug a smaller uncertainty in momentum into the uncertainty formula of Heisenberg, you will get that your uncertainty in place increases, so my chances of tunneling increases as well. Could you help me to figure out if my reasoning is correct? Mind you that I am following a high school physics course, so I do not have a very deep understanding of the subject.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I left it out completely as it did not add much value to the question. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: So you have $\lambda\propto 1/T$, but where does the HUP come in? As in, what situation are you considering that has a temperature-dependent momentum that you're asking about tunneling? And what reasoning are you questioning?

Answer (score 1):

The de Broglie wavelength doesn't generally depend on temperature. It depends only on the momentum $p$ of a free particle. You are probably assuming to have a free particle with three degrees of freedom with an effective thermal kinetic energy $$E_K=\pi kT=\frac {p^2}{2m}$$ Then the so-called [thermal de Broglie wavelength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_de_Broglie_wavelength) is given by $$\lambda_{th}= \frac {h}{p}=\frac {h}{\sqrt {2 m E_K}}=\frac{h}{\sqrt {2\pi m kT}}$$ Thus, indeed, the thermal de Broglie wavelength increases with decreasing temperature.

If you are looking at the tunnel probability of such a thermal particle through a constant square potential barrier with a top energy $E_B$, the energy difference between the top of the barrier and the particle energy $E_K$, $E_B-E_K$, will increase. Therefore the tunnel probability of the thermal particle through the barrier will **decrease** with decreasing temperature, because the effective energetic barrier height $E_B-E_K$ increases with decreasing temperature.

For this qualitative reasoning the de Broglie wavelength is not necessary. If you want a quantitative tunneling probability estimate, you will get an estimate using the (exponential) damping constant of the evanescent wave in the barrier region and the thickness of the barrier.